# How run multiple users simultaneously in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In our application total 500 users I want 10 users hit request same time . How to achieve it?
I also used Synchronizing timer and uniform random timer for delay and waiting for user .
can I use both timer in one group?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to execute a certain request by 10 users at the same time - add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of this request and set "Number of Simulated Users to Group by" to `10`

   [image]
2. [Uniform Random Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer) can be used in combination with Synchronizing Timer, it will add the configured delay before each Sampler it its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) so if you want to apply the delay before each request - put the Uniform Random Timer just under the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

   [image]